# Retrieve docs if specific value exists in array column of elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to search value in elastic search. Here is code that I have written in PHP

```
$categories= 32;        
$params = [
            'index' => 'indexname',
            'body'  => [
                'query' => [
                    'term' => [
                        'categories' => $categories,
                    ],
                ],
                'size' => 100
            ]
        ];
        $response = $client->search($params);
```

What I want is to get all records having 32 value in array column. E.g We have doc with category fields having value like this:

```
doc 1- [categories] => [32]
doc 2- [categories] => [50,32]
doc 3- [categories] => [20]
```

Mapping of category field is:

```
"categories": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "global_search_analyzer",
    "fielddata": true
 }
```

Real Doc looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_index] => text_dummy
            [_type] => _doc
            [_id] => t=j0-422fgndlvnv
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [price] => 2
                    [categories] => [32]
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_index] => text_dummy
            [_type] => _doc
            [_id] => g=ti-rjfnlaid
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [price] => 12
                    [categories] => [32,50]
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [_index] => text_dummy
        [_type] => _doc
        [_id] =>rg=svggr5hfgf
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [price] => 20
                [categories] => [20]
            )
    )
```

Expected output should be having 2 hits with doc 1 and doc 2 but I am getting only 1 record
Please help to achieve this result. If anybody needs more info, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you did looks correct. What is the mapping type of the `categories` field? Also can you share how the real categories values look like in the real documents?

Comment: @Val I have edited the question and mentioned mapping , real doc . May it help to understand you more

Comment: Thanks, what is the definition of `global_search_analyzer`? Also why store numerical categories as analyzed text?

Comment: @val Here is global_search_analyzer definition
"analyzer" => [
                            "global_search_analyzer" => [
                                "type" => "custom",
                                "filter" => [
                                    "lowercase"
                                ],
                                "tokenizer" => "standard"
                            ]
                        ]
Categories is having product category ID's

Comment: My question is why analyzing numbers (i.e. it makes no sense to lowercase a number)? Or are 32 and 50 just dummy categories and the real ones are strings?

Comment: No, 30 and 50 are real numbers as mentioned in example above, I will delete global_search_analyzer mapping for this field. Actually indexer is already created before

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Using the information you provided, your query returns the two documents you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256089/discussion-between-sukhpal-singh-and-val).